# Overfitting on a Small DataSet Sanity Check?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I'm doing image classification for two classes using the pretrained Inception V3 model. As a sanity check I've over fit my model on a small data set of 20 images. The training results appear to over fit properly, however I'm unsure what the expected output of the validation accuracy and loss should be. How do I properly do this sanity check to see if my model works correctly?

[image]

```
data = np.array(data, dtype="float")/255.0
labels = np.array(labels,dtype ="uint8")

#test_size is percentage to split into test/train data
(trainX, testX, trainY, testY) = train_test_split(
                            data,labels, 
                            test_size=0.2, 
                            random_state=42) 

img_width, img_height = 299, 299 #InceptionV3 size

epochs =  25
batch_size = 64

#include_top = false to accomodate new classes 
base_model = keras.applications.InceptionV3(
        weights ='imagenet',
        include_top=False, 
        input_shape = (img_width,img_height,3))

#Classifier Model ontop of Convolutional Model
model_top = keras.models.Sequential()
model_top.add(keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(input_shape=base_model.output_shape[1:], data_format=None)),
model_top.add(keras.layers.Dense(350,activation='relu'))
#model_top.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.4))
model_top.add(keras.layers.Dense(1,activation = 'sigmoid'     
model = keras.models.Model(inputs = base_model.input, outputs = model_top(base_model.output))

model.compile(optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(
                    lr=0.00001,
                    beta_1=0.9,
                    beta_2=0.999,
                    epsilon=1e-08),
                    loss='binary_crossentropy',
                    metrics=['accuracy'])

train_datagen = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
          zoom_range = 0.05,
          width_shift_range = 0.05, 
          height_shift_range = 0.05,
          horizontal_flip = True,
          vertical_flip = True,
          fill_mode ='nearest') 


val_datagen = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator()


train_generator = train_datagen.flow(
        trainX, 
        trainY,
        batch_size=batch_size)

validation_generator = val_datagen.flow(
                testX,
                testY,
                batch_size=batch_size)
```

Answer (score 0):

Split your dataset into test, development, and train. Check out how your accuracy and loss changed in development set compared to your training set. To this end, you can get the help from [Tensorboard callback](https://keras.io/callbacks/) in Keras:

```
tbCallBack = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='./Graph', histogram_freq=0, write_graph=True, write_images=True)
...
model.fit(...inputs and parameters..., callbacks=[tbCallBack])
```

[image]

You can also check your accuracy with the original paper as well.